# I am trying to scrape a wikipedia world capitals page for the country and capital pairs

Tags: python, web-scraping

The program works for a short time and then hits an error and I have no idea what it means or how to fix it.
Here is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

BASE_URL = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_national_capitals_in_alphabetical_order"

capitals_countries = []

html = urllib.urlopen(BASE_URL).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
country_table = soup.find('table', {"class" : "wikitable sortable"})

for row in country_table.find_all('tr'):
    cols = row.find_all('td')

    if len(cols) == 3:
        capitals_countries.append((cols[0].text.strip(), cols[1].text.strip()))

for capital, country in capitals_countries:
    print('{:35} {}'.format(capital, country))
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Kyle/Documents/scraper.py", line 19, in <module>
    print('{:35} {}'.format(capital, country))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe1' in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have a rather basic understanding of html and scraping in general. I would appreciate any clarity that anyone can provide me for what is going on here.

Comment: Looks like an encoding issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a unicode string, trying to `capital.decode('utf-8'),` that is going to give you:

```
In [13]: s =  u'\xe1'
In [14]: print s
á  
In [15]: s.decode("utf-8")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-61efbeae9c77> in <module>()
----> 1 s.decode("utf-8")

/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.pyc in decode(input, errors)
     14 
     15 def decode(input, errors='strict'):
---> 16     return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
     17 
     18 class IncrementalEncoder(codecs.IncrementalEncoder):

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe1' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The reason you see it in your own code is you are trying to do the same using `str.format` when you call format on the unicode string you are trying to encode the string to ascii which fails as you have non ascii characters:

```
In [16]: print "{}".format(s)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-1119d22adcca> in <module>()
----> 1 print "{}".format(s)

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe1' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

All you need is to make the `str.format` string a unicode string with a leading `u`, do not decode anything:

```
In [17]: print u"{}".format(s)
á
```

So in your own code you need a leading `u` on your format string, nothing else.

```
for capital, country in capitals_countries:
    print(u'{:35} {}'.format(capital, country))
```

You can verify that you have a unicode string by just adding a print type(capital)  which a would output `<type 'unicode'>`.

Comment: Thank you for the detail and explanation. It works just perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix the issue:

```
print('{:35} {}'.format(capital.decode('utf-8'), country.decode('utf-8')))
```

Or as suggested by @karlson in the comment, we can also use unicode strings like:

```
print(u'{:35} {}'.format(capital, country))
```

Now the `u'{:35} {}'` part is unicode, so you don't need to decode it any more.

Comment: Thanks, yes, adding it to the answer.

Comment: The solution here is correct but your description is not. The characters are already UTF-8; decoding them converts them to Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

When I looked at the list I see that the code broke at Bogotá

I think it's breaking due to special character á

When I change the print statement to

```
print(u'{:35} {}'.format(capital, country))
```

It works perfectly fine

Comment: Can you please explain the reason for negative vote. Please let me know if the code doesn't work

Comment: The negative vote wasn't me; the code works perfectly.

Comment: No problem . Thanks a lot